# Stop Playing All Media Element on Page in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp

I am creating dynamic media elements along with a dynamic button on a xaml page like this:

```
MediaElement audioElement= new MediaElement();
audioElement.Source = new Uri(ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path + "\\"+ audioFileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
audioElement.AutoPlay = false;
audioElement.Volume = 1;
```

Then playing the audio on click of a button:

```
 audioElement.Play();
```

How to stop all previously playing media element and play only one audio at a time as there are multiple media elements with different sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue with using a global MediaElement and playing and pausing the same media element, by assinging the source at the time of clik of play button.

Hope this helps.

```
if (null != audioPlayerElement.Source)
                    {
                        audioPlayerElement.Stop();
                        FrameworkElement elem = this.ContentPanel.FindName(audioPlayerElement.Tag.ToString()) as FrameworkElement;
                        RelativePanel audioPanel = elem as RelativePanel;

                        Button playButton = (from im in audioPanel.Children.OfType<Button>() select im).FirstOrDefault();
                        playButton.Tag = "PAUSED";
                        ImageBrush backgroundImage = new ImageBrush();
                        backgroundImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/Video_Play_button.png"));
                        backgroundImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                        playButton.Background = backgroundImage;

                        Slider prevSlider = (from im in audioPanel.Children.OfType<Slider>() select im).FirstOrDefault();
                        prevSlider.Value = 0;
                    }
```

`audioPlayerElement = audioElement;`

assigning the local media element to global media element again.